# Get all index and types' names from cluster in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my cluster and I want to know all indexes and types' names in it. I use Sense.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

will give you all the indexes.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty=true'
```

will give you the document types in these indexes, together with their mappings.

Comment: This works.  While it would be nice to have a query that just lists the types, when i add "?pretty" to the query it gives me a very nice breakdown of all field mappings for all types (which solves the next question I had).  -- Thx.

Comment: /_cat/indices?v giving me error like this -> {"error":"NullPointerException[null]","status":500}

Comment: Do not forget you can add `?pretty=true` for an indented readable JSON

Comment: In this case, one consult show just the type of the data, how i can unmake this for that i can see the data itself?

Answer (score 32):

The answer by yvespeirsman is correct but if you want to just see types for indexes you can use jq to get a more compact answer.

```
curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_mapping' | jq 'to_entries | .[] | {(.key): .value.mappings | keys}'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I can see that it would make sense to parse out the types.  Too bad that ES doesn't offer a simple command like _types to do so.

Comment: @InformationTechnology - try an aggregation in this situation.

Comment: Package: jq
Description: lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor
 jq is like sed for JSON data – you can use it to slice
 and filter and map and transform structured data with
 the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you
 play with text.
 .
 It is written in portable C, and it has minimal runtime
 dependencies.
 .
 jq can mangle the data format that you have into the
 one that you want with very little effort, and the
 program to do so is often shorter and simpler than
 you’d expect.

Answer (score 17):

Some mappings are too large to efficiently use the `_mapping` to parse out types. Instead consider an [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html). Would likely be much faster. For indexes:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_search" -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "indicesAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index",
        "size": 200
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

And for types for a specific index (or to get all types across all indexes, simply exclude the index name {myIndex} in the url):

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myIndex/_search" -d'
{
  "aggs": {
    "typesAgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type",
        "size": 200
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

I'm sure you could write a single agg to return both as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the mappings inside index:

```
    GET /{index_name}/_search?size=50
    {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
```