# Using elasticsearch NEST on a remote index

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch-5

This is probably just me completely overseeing the obvious "missing link". Here goes anyway: I have an elasticsearch end-point http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search, and I would like to query on this end-point. Fairly simple.

As I understand, NEST gives you the ability to strongly type the interaction with the elasticsearch index, in much the same way as Visual Studio will create types for a asmx/svc when you add a reference to the respective service.

So my question is: how on earth do I get from knowing the end-point for an elasticsearch index to having types matching the index and making queries on the index? I pressume the answer is: "Use NEST!", but all tutorials I've been able to find assume you have a local index that you generate from a c#-type, which will then give you a type to use in your queries. But what to do, when it's a "remote" index that you have to build your types from?

Thanks in advance for any answer pointing in the right direction!

**UPDATE:**

I have retrieved the mappings in the index, which I have reduced to only the field "cvrNummer" in the following:

```
{
"cvr-permanent-prod-20170205" : {
"mappings" : {
  "virksomhed" : {
    "_size" : {
      "enabled" : true
    },
    "properties" : {
      "Vrvirksomhed" : {
        "properties" : {

            "type" : "long"
          },
          "cvrNummer" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },             

          }
        }
      },          
    }
  }
  }
 }
 }
```

I have then made the following class:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "virksomhed")]
public class Company
{
    [Text(Name = "cvrNummer")]
    public string cvrNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now, all that I want to do (to begin with) is to search for documents having cvrNummer with a certain value, f. ex. "12883404". I have the following code in a simple console application:

```
var node = new Uri("http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-
permanent/virksomhed/_search");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("defaultindex");

        settings.BasicAuthentication("username", "password");            

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

I then try the following very simple request:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Company>(s => s
.Type<Company>()
.Query(q => q
     .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.cvrNumber)
        .Query("12883404")
```

And I get "400 bad request". What on earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you create a C# class with the properties you need by hand, then tell nest to map the results to this class.

```
using Nest;
using System;

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "Name_Of_The_Mapping_In_Index_Mappings")]
public class MySearchType {

        [Text(Name = "_id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [Number(NumberType.Long, Name = "some_numeric_property_in_the_mapping")] 
        public long SomeNumericProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can type your results to the search type you just defined:

```
Task<ISearchResponse<MySearchType>> response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<MySearchType>(s => s
    .Index("Name_Of_The_Index")
    .Type<MySearchType>()
    .Query(q => 
        q.Bool(bo => 
             bo.Filter( 
                 f => f.Terms(t => 
                     t.Field(searchtype => searchtype.SomeNumericProperty).Terms(request.NumericInput)),
                 /* ... */
             )
         )
     )
);

IReadOnylCollection<MySearchType> result = response.Documents;
```

This explains how you can retrieve the names needed to create the binding: [Get all index and types' names from cluster in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087204/get-all-index-and-types-names-from-cluster-in-elasticsearch).

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, getting a "400 bad request" from the end-point. I have edited my question with details of the service, please have a look at that.

Comment: Does it work if you use a simple query without binding to your search type? E.g. `_elasticClient.Search<dynamic>(s => s.Index("Name_Of_The_Index").AllTypes().From(0).Size(10));` Just to make sure the `_elasticClient` is configured properly....

Comment: AHHHHH, seems I found the issue: it worked when I used url http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-
permanent with defaultindex=virksomhed. Before it appended index and _search to the url giving a wrong end-point, ie. http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-
permanent/virksomhed/_search/virksomhed/_search. So now just need to results mapped to Company class :)

Comment: So, the question is reduced to: how do I make the simple search that I mentioned, and get cvrNummer field (in the mapping mentioned in the update in the question) mapped to the cvrNumber property in the Company class in the response? :)

Comment: Hm looks like `cvrNummer` is nested inside `Vrvirksomhed`; please try to bind from `[Text(Name = "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer")]` (hope that works).

Comment: Sigh. Tried var searchResponse = client.Search<Company>(s => s.AllTypes().From(0).Size(10)); with [Text(Name = "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer")]. I get 10 documents with the type Company, but they have cvrNumber = null.

Comment: I now tried the search var searchResponse = client.Search<Company>(s => s
    .AllTypes().Query(q => q
         .Match(m => m
            .Field(f => f.cvrNumber)
            .Query("12883404")
         )
    )
); ------------------ which gives 1 hit as expected, and the 1 hit has the correct information, but still the value of Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer is not bound to Company.cvrNumber, ie. one Company is returned i searchResponse.Documents, but the  value of cvrNumber on the Company is null

Comment: You shouldn't set `[Text(Name = "_id")]` on the `Id` property. The `Id` property will create an `id` field in the `_source` document, with NEST having a convention to use the value in the `Id` property as the value for the `_id` metadata field (which is _not_ part of `_source` document).

Comment: This question is resolved in [my other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533591/elasticsearch-how-to-make-nest-map-response-to-class)