# Elasticsearch, how to make NEST map response to class

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

First of all, I am using NEST 5.5.0.

I have the following use of a remote elasticsearch-index:

```
var node = new Uri("http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent");

        var settings = new 
ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("virksomhed");

        settings.BasicAuthentication("username", "password");

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var searchResponse = client.Search<Company>(s => s
.AllTypes().Query(q => q
     .Match(m => m
        .Field(f => f.cvrNumber)
        .Query("35954716")
     )
)
);
```

The mappings in the index (without a bunch of other properties besides cvrNummer) are as follows:

```
{
"cvr-permanent-prod-20170205" : {
"mappings" : {
"virksomhed" : {
"_size" : {
  "enabled" : true
},
"properties" : {
  "Vrvirksomhed" : {
    "properties" : {

        "type" : "long"
      },
      "cvrNummer" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },             

      }
    }
  },          
}
}
}
}
}
```

I also have the following class which the result is supposed to be mapped to:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "virksomhed")]
public class Company
{
    [Text(Name = "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer")]
    public string cvrNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the search (searchResponse) holds the expected results (1 result), where the part concerning cvrNummer looks as follows:

```
"hits": {
"total": 1,
"max_score": 17.34601,
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "cvr-permanent-prod-20170205",
    "_type": "virksomhed",
    "_id": "4000333383",
    "_score": 17.34601,
    "_source": {
      "Vrvirksomhed": {
        "cvrNummer": 35954716,
        "regNummer": [
          {
            "regnummer": "A/S35855",
            "periode": {
              "gyldigFra": "1956-06-01",
              "gyldigTil": "1999-10-18"
            },
            "sidstOpdateret": "2015-02-10T00:00:00.000+01:00"
          }
        ],
        "brancheAnsvarskode": null,
        "reklamebeskyttet": false,
        "navne": [
...
```

However, when i look in searchResponse.Documents, I have the correct type (Company), but the value of cvrNumber is null.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, since the value of cvrNummer is not mapped into cvrNumber on the instance of Company in searchResponse.Documents?

Thanks in advance for your input!

**UPDATE**

I tried the following without success, still got the expected result, but cvrNumber is still null (in searchResponse.Documents):

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "virksomhed")]
public class Company
{
    [Object(Name = "Vrvirksomhed")]
    public Vrvirksomhed Vrvirksomhed { get; set; }
}

public class Vrvirksomhed
{
    [Text(Name = "cvrNummer")]
    public string cvrNumber { get; set; }
}
```

With the query:

```
 var searchResponse = client.Search<Vrvirksomhed>(s => s
            .AllTypes().Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.cvrNumber)
                    .Query("35954716")
                )
            )
        );
```

**UPDATE**

It works with the following modifications to the query:

```
 var searchResponse = client.Search<Company>(s => s
            .AllTypes().Query(q => q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Vrvirksomhed.cvrNumber)
                    .Query("35954716")
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: 5.x (and some more characters here, since 5.x is too short to be a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [ElasticsearchType(Name = "virksomhed")]
> public class Company
> {
>     [Text(Name = "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer")]
>     public string cvrNumber { get; set; }
> }
> ```

`Vrvirksomhed` looks like it should be a POCO property on `Company` mapped either as an [object datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) or [nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) (take a look at [nested objects in the Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) for the differences), where that POCO has a property called `cvrNumber`, similar to

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "virksomhed")]
public class Company
{
    [Object(Name = "Vrvirksomhed")]
    public Vrvirksomhed Vrvirksomhed { get; set; }
}

public class Vrvirksomhed
{
    [Text(Name = "cvrNummer")]
    public string cvrNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do I then put the type Vrvirksomhed into the query, ie.: var searchResponse = client.Search<Vrvirksomhed>(s => s .AllTypes().Query(q => q .Match(m => m .Field(f => f.cvrNumber) .Query("35954716") ) ) ); I tried that, and it still doesn't work (se me update to the question)

Comment: No, you still query on `Company`, and use `f => f.Vrvirksomhed.cvrNumber` as the expression for the field

Comment: Omg, it works, and I think I've seen (some of) the light. Thank you! :)

Comment: No worries @KimSchioett :) Did you see the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't crack the nut for me (to me, it seemed to always assume that you generate the index yourself from a mapping).

Comment: I see. Thanks, that's useful feedback!