# How many document and indices types (and count them by type) in the ElasticSearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to know exactly how many document types and indices are in an ElasticSearch server.

I'm using the python client.

I know how to search by field, in a certain connection/server, and in a certain index.  But I don't know how to do it for any possible document, or index, that may exist in the server.

Comment: Your question is answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087204/get-all-index-and-types-names-from-cluster-in-elasticsearch

Comment: @AshishJain those answers are only in curl form. I'm looking for answers for the python client...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. StackOverFlow is not a code for hire community. Based off the previous answer, what have you tried and what error do you face ?

But I believe you could be using the function https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.3.3/api.html#elasticsearch.client.CatClient.indices

Answer (score 0):

```
connection = elasticsearch_dsl.connections.get_connection()
# a pretty string with information on all indices
connection.cat.indices(v=True)

# length on all indices
len(connection.indices.stats()["indices"])

# number of all docs
connection.cat.count(v=True)
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.